# How to convert string into datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime, beautifulsoup

In a dataframe, if a subset of a date column is 02.03 (month.date), how can I convert it to dateTime format so that the subsets are saved as a data format when being exported to Excel.

```
 reference_date_str = reference_date
 reference_date_obj = datetime.strptime(reference_date_str, '%y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: what are you using to write to excel? xlsxwriter or through pandas?

Comment: `%y` is for 2-digit year. Use uppercase `%Y` for 4-digit year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you pass a format that matches the structure of your string.
if the string is using dots, then the format structure should be similar.

This should do the trick:

```
reference_date = tr.find('td').text
reference_date_with_year = f"2023.{reference_date}"
reference_date_obj = datetime.strptime(reference_date_with_year, '%Y.%m.%d')
print(reference_date_obj)
```

output:

```
2023-02-03 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
reference_date = '2023.' + reference_date
reference_date_obj = datetime.strptime(reference_date_str, '%Y.%m.%d')
excel_date=reference_date_obj.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")
```

if you are using pandas to write to excel sheet, you can pass the date in any format as long as you specify the format in your stmt

```
pd.ExcelWriter("abc.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter',date_format='YYYY.MM.DD')
```

Comment: how to apply date_format using ExcelWriter to "reference_date_obj"?

Comment: not for individual variables likereference_date_obj, but for an entire dataframe where date is in one or more columns.